# HTTP POST in android device with localhost and port

Tags: android, url, localhost, port

I want to make a post on http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8083/AuthenticationService.svc/SignIn in an android app. The x's represent the localhost and 8083 is the port. This works very well on the computer, but how do I get the localhost numbers (and possibly the port, if it differs) in an android app?
I've only found answers on how to get the emulator running by using a certain number for localhost, but not the straightforward answer for an actual android app ran on the device (phone).
I mention that I know how to make the post, I just need to know how to form the URL mentioned. Thanks

Comment: So the android device is running a web server and listening on that port? localhost is 127.0.0.1

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what localhost means... it turns out that it worked by simply using http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8083/AuthenticationService.svc/SignIn . Also, I got the networkingOnMainThreadException, so I just made an asyncTask and put the code there. Anyway, thanks all. The answers put me on the right track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once an app goes off to a device, it needs to be pointed to the IP address (or DNS name) of the server you want it to talk to.  In Linux you can find the server's IP address with `ifconfig`.  Or in Windows, `ipconfig`.